# MMS Intent ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, mms

I need to send MMS from my Activity, but i don`t know how to do it without Intent.
with Intent, I'm posting so:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra("address", "number");
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "body");
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Image/Android/1_Hazey_Android.jpg"));
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        sendIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send Image To:"),1);
```

for 3 days I am suffering with this.
I seen in android market apps: handsend sms, chompr sms, go sms, who send mms from his app.
me need to do well.

tell me how to do this.

---

Sorry for my English

Comment: Yes, it would be interesting to look at it. Now I can send mms but there is a problem with attached files (that is the most important in mms). For some reason recipient can't open it.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://androidbridge.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-send-mms-programmatically-in.html)
 will give you the answer to your question: how to send SMS on the attached content

I use Nokia Java based MMS implementation.

For receiving MMS I use class 
[MmsMonitor](http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/where-can-i-find-information-about-sending-receiving-mms-t51284.html)

P.S. The recipient of the data at least some are coming from?

Comment: Hey @alezhka, i looked into the examples you gave of sending MMS, but I am having some issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-sms-mms-in-android . How did you get this to work?